# How to make my background image not get smaller when i make the window smaller?

Tags: html, css

my background image gets smaller when i make the webpage window smaller. Right now it isn't repeating (which is a steo forward), now i just need it to cover the full screen to not show white around the backgorund when window gets smaller.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color #333;
}


/*---Background Image---*/

body.home {
  background-image: URL("http://www.freepngimg.com/download/home/2-2-home-png-file.png");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  ` background-color: #333;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body class="home">
  <section class="Navbar">
    <div>
      <header>
        <div>
          <a class="logo" href="Index.html">
            <img src="http://e-2103.jp/images/bt_nav_area_search.jpg" height="57.6px" width="190px">
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="Index.html">HOME</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: change `background-size`to a fixed size

Comment: You have a backtick here too `\` background-color: #333;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `body` element is only as big as the content inside, so the background does not fill the entire window height.

To fix this, you could tell `body` to never be smaller than the window height, like so:

```
.body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

See jsfiddle with this change: http://jsfiddle.net/L2ynhxcf/

You can remove `min-height: 100vh;` and you will see the body height shrinks back down to about 80px - and the problem appears again.